# Spreading elements with no duplicates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for the way to remove duplicates. I found a common way is to create a Set and then spread into a new Array.

How could I Set to acomplish this purpose? For instance, I have the following code:

```
const tmp1=[];
const tmp2=[{
    guid:"e695d848-7188-4741-9c95-44bec634940f",
    name: "Spreading.pdf",
    code: "G1"
  }];
const tmp = [...new Set([...tmp1],[...tmp2])]; //This should remove duplicates, but gets empty array
const x = [...tmp1, ...tmp2]; // This would keep duplicates
```

The issue is that because tmp1 is an empty array, then I am getting empty result. However, if I do the following, then getting correct result:

```
const tmp = [...new Set(...tmp1,[...tmp2])];
```

I think something is missing in here.

This is an example of duplicated entries where Set is working like a charm just keeping one record:

```
const tmp1=[{
    guid:"e695d848-7188-4741-9c95-44bec634940f",
    name: "Spreading.pdf",
    code: "G1"
  }];
const tmp2=[{
    guid:"e695d848-7188-4741-9c95-44bec634940f",
    name: "Spreading.pdf",
    code: "G1"
  }];
const tmp = [...new Set([...tmp1],[...tmp2])];
```

This was the original idea, but how about if one of the lists is empty. Then, I am getting an empty array if this occurs.

Thank you

Comment: What is duplicate with an object? All the properties are the same?

Comment: in the example there are no duplicates (I guess the title of question is misleading). The issue is when spreading an empty array in Set which is used to avoid possible duplicates.

Comment: if make it as `const tmp = [...new Set([...tmp1, ...tmp2])]`, it will work but for primitive value only.

Comment: What is an example with duplicates???? Objects are not going to work with set. Plenty of ways to handle it, but what makes it a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set should take 1 argument but it's taking 2, merge them into one:

```js
const tmp = [...new Set([...tmp1, ...tmp2])];
```

Note: that this method won't remove duplicates because you are passing an object to the set and not a reference for it, in this case, you can do this instead:

```js
const tmp1 = [];
const tmp2 = [{
  guid: "e695d848-7188-4741-9c95-44bec634940f",
  name: "Spreading.pdf",
  code: "G1"
},
{
  guid: "e695d848-7188-4741-9c95-44bec634940f",
  name: "Spreading.pdf",
  code: "G1"
}
];

// pass a special unique key that differs object from each other to item, in this case i passed guid
const tmp = [...new Map([...tmp1, ...tmp2].map(item => [item['guid'], item])).values()]
```

Comment: Will it work on array of **objects**?

Comment: @kinduser updated with proper way

Comment: The solution looks fantastic, using a Map object is going to enforce uniqueness due to the guid.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain why this example in the question seemingly work:

```
const tmp1=[{
    guid:"e695d848-7188-4741-9c95-44bec634940f",
    name: "Spreading.pdf",
    code: "G1"
  }];
const tmp2=[{
    guid:"e695d848-7188-4741-9c95-44bec634940f",
    name: "Spreading.pdf",
    code: "G1"
  }];
const tmp = [...new Set([...tmp1],[...tmp2])];
```

It results in one object because `Set()` only take one iterable object, so it takes the first one.

If `const tmp2=[1, 2, 3]` in the above example, `tmp` will still result in the one object in `tmp1`.

[More about `Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set)